# ¿Cómo se pueden validar campos en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagrid

Tengo un dataGridview, de NxN, con valores ascendentes, como en la siguiente foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se pueden validar directamente en el DataGridView el valor de la celda editada para que el usuario no ingrese un dato inferior a la celda anterior? Esto sin necesidad de crear un arreglo previamente.

Comment: Hola Mareyes bienvenid@! te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También puedes revisar [como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Saludos @Mareyes, seria bueno que pusieras un poco de codigo para saber como generaste tu datagrid, y otras cosas que son necesarias para lo que pides

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que interactúas con tu aplicación, un evento es activado. Para solucionar tu problema debes hacer uso de el evento `CellValidating` de la clase `DataGridView`. Este evento se activa cada vez que el usuario deja de editar el contenido de una casilla del objeto de la clase `DataGridView`. Para aprovechar este evento necesitas crear un método al que enlaces el evento del `DataGridView`.

Suponiendo que al tu referirte a la casilla anterior, haces referencia a la que se encuentra a la izquierda, el código de la función que sería ejecutada por el evento `CellValidating` sería el siguiente:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Este es el mensaje que se muestra al generarse un error al validar.
    ObjetoDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
    DataGridViewCell CasillaAnterior;

    // Forma de asignar la casilla anterior.
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
    {
        CasillaAnterior = ObjetoDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].Cells[ObjetoDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1];
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
    {
         CasillaAnterior = ObjetoDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        CasillaAnterior = null;
    }

    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.FormattedValue) <= Convert.ToInt32(CasillaAnterior.Value))
    {
        // De esta manera indicamos que no acepte el valor ingresado.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Claramente debes configurar en el objeto de la clase `DataGridView` que cuando ocurra este evento, ejecute la función del código anterior.

> Aquí te dejo un par de páginas de el MSDN de Microsoft para que
>   obtengas más información:
>
> [Evento DataGridView.CellValidating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Clase DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Mira el siguiente ejemplo:
>
> ```
> private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
> {
>     dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
>     int newInteger;
>
>     // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished 
>     // editing since there
>     // is not any point in validating its initial value.
>     if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) { return; }
>     if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out newInteger) || newInteger < 0)
>      {
>          e.Cancel = true;
>          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "the value must be a non-negative integer";
>     }
> }
> ```